# Build own "SDK" to put in other 3rd application

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries

I have to create "`library`" that allow other developers use it in their applications.
My library will be simple -

Developers will call our lib's api f.e. create button (pre-defined in our lib) and add to his subview.

**What is the best way to create this kind of lib? 
Should it be "static" library or something else?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static library is probably the best way to go. You *can't* use dynamic library loading on iOS (unless you're Apple).

Static libraries are pretty easy to create these days. There's a target you can use in Xcode and, basically, you just put the right files in it. It used to be much harder.

If you're not willing to share your code it might be the only option. If you *are* willing to share your code, you can just distribute the files and instructions of which need adding to other projects. It still might be nicer to make a library available.

Comment: thanks, hope this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFn2o0aEbRQ good point to start

Answer (score 1):

The best way for your and the developers is to create a static library.

It would result with a .a file and some .h

To do so, just open Xcode, new Projet, then Framework & Library => cocoa touch static library.